# Ruby: Split a string into substring of maximum 40 characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I have some strings with a sentence and i need to subdivise it into a substring of maximum 40 characters.
But i don't want to split the sentence in the middle of a word.

I tried with .gsub function but it's return 40 characters maximum and avoid to cut the string in the middle of a word. But it's return only the first occurence.

```
sentence[0..40].gsub(/\s\w+$/,'')
```

I tried with split but i can select only the fist 40 characters and split in the middle of a word...

```
sentence.split(...){40}
```

My string is `"Sure, we will show ourselves only when we know the east door has been opened."`.
The string output i want is

```
 ["Sure, we will show ourselves only when we","know the east door has
 been opened."]
```

Do you have a solution ? Thanks

Comment: Try `sentence[/\A.{0,40}\b/m]`

Comment: Do you have a sentence example, and what the output should be?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it's return only the first occurence.

Comment: @EricDuminil my string sentence example is "Sure, we will show ourselves only when we know the east door has been opened.". I want this string output: ["Sure, we will show ourselves only when we","know the east door has been opened."]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first attempt:

```
sentence[0..40].gsub(/\s\w+$/,'')
```

*almost* works, but it has one fatal flaw. You are splitting on the number of characters **before** cutting off the last word. This means you have *no way of knowing* whether the bit being trimmed off was a whole word, or a partial word.

Because of this, your code will *always cut off the last word*.

I would solve the problem as follows:

```
sentence[/\A.{0,39}[a-z]\b/mi]
```

- `\A` is an anchor to fix the regex to the start of the string.
- `.{0,39}[a-z]` matches on 1 to 40 characters, where *the last character must be a letter*. This is to prevent the last selected character from being punctuation or space. (Is that desired behaviour? Your question didn't really specify. Feel free to tweak/remove that `[a-z]` part, e.g. `[a-z.]` to match a full stop, if desired.)
- `\b` is a word boundary look-around. It is a zero-width matcher, on beginning/end of words.
- `/mi` modifiers will include case insensitive (i.e. `A-Z`) and multi-line matches.

One very minor note is that because this regex is matching **1** to 40 characters (rather than zero), it is possible to get a null result. (Although this is seemingly very unlikely, since you'd need a 1-word, 41+ letter string!!) To account for this edge case, call `.to_s` on the result if needed.

---

**Update**: Thank you for the improved edit to your question, providing a concrete example of an input/result. This makes it much clearer what you are asking for, as the original post was somewhat ambiguous.

You could solve this with something like the following:

```
sentence.scan(/.{0,39}[a-z.!?,;](?:\b|$)/mi)
```

- `String#scan` returns an *array* of strings that match the pattern - so you can then re-join these strings to reconstruct the original.
- Again, I have added a few more characters (`!?,;`) to the list of "final characters in the substring". Feel free to tweak this as desired.
- `(?:\b|$)` means "either a word boundary, *or the end of the line*". This fixes the issue of the result not including the final `.` in the substrings. Note that I have used a non-capture group (`?:`) to prevent the result of `scan` from changing.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help but it's return me only the first occurence. My example is "Sure, we will show ourselves only when we know the east door has been opened.".                                                                                         I want this string output: ["Sure, we will show ourselves only when we","know the east door has been opened."]

Comment: Tom, it's almost works but i don't have the last charactere in the array output. I mean the dot. It's could be . | ! | ? Do you have an idea ? Thank you. Enjoy your day ;-)

Comment: Hi @Blueone, I've updated my answer above now that i'm back at a keyboard.

Comment: Hi @tom-lord, your update works !! Thank you so much for your help. I'm new into the world of development but i will keep in mind your advice for my next questions on Stackoverflow to be clearer. Great day!